# Fluent NHibernate to query stored procedure without an hbm.xml mapping

Tags: stored-procedures, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

Is there any way to query stored procedure in Fluent Nhibernate without creating an hbm.xml file mapping?

Answer (score 30):

I assume you use the standard

```
Session.GetNamedQuery(....
```

instead, you can use

```
var result = Session.CreateSQLQuery("exec MyStoredProc :pUserId, :pIsLocked")
                    .AddEntity(typeof(MyDomainObject))
                    .SetParameter("pUserId", userId)
                    .SetParameter("pIsLocked", isLocked)
                    .List<MyDomainObject>();
```

This allows you to call the stored proc but still get back a domain object (or list of) without needing a .hbm.xml file.

[Actually there's this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2574647/563692)

Answer (score 5):

You should have a class for returning result set in my case it's GameActivity class

```
    public class GameActivity
    {
            public virtual DateTime Date { get; set; }
            public virtual string GameRoundId { get; set; }
            public virtual int GameProvider { get; set; }
            public virtual string GameName { get; set; }
            public virtual decimal RealBet { get; set; }
            public virtual decimal RealWin { get; set; }
            public virtual decimal BonusBet { get; set; }
            public virtual decimal BonusWin { get; set; }
            public virtual decimal BonusContribution { get; set; }
            public virtual int IsRoundCompleted { get; set; }
            public virtual int IsRoundCancelled { get; set; }
    }
```

Calling stored procedure "GetMemberGameActivity" to get the list

```
    var result = session.CreateSQLQuery("exec GetMemberGameActivity :mToken, :StartDate, :EndDate")
                        .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean())
                        .SetParameter("mToken", token)
                        .SetParameter("StartDate", startDate)
                        .SetParameter("EndDate", endDate)
                        .List().ToList();
```

Comment: Valid answer, only if you export to a generic list you need to specified the generic class. for example in my case the result is a IList<T1098Dto>  then I need to modify the answer to:                          var result = repository.Session.CreateSQLQuery("exec USP_SA_Get1098TDataForTaxYear :TaskYear, :CampusId")
                    .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<T1098Dto>())
                    .SetParameter("TaskYear", filter.Year)
                    .SetParameter("CampusId", filter.CampusId)
                    .List<T1098Dto>().ToList();

Comment: this answer is working
var result = session.CreateSQLQuery("exec GetMemberGameActivity :mToken, :StartDate, :EndDate")
                        .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<T>())
                        .SetParameter("mToken", token)
                        .SetParameter("StartDate", startDate)
                        .SetParameter("EndDate", endDate)
                        .List().ToList();

Answer (score 1):

some good answers here however I want to make a more generic solution where I can pass in the object I want out and dynamically set my stored procedure parameters.

```
 public RequestList<T> FetchExport<T>(Integration_ExportType exportType)
     {
         var returnRequest = new RequestList<T>{Success = true};
         try
         {
             string sql = "EXEC "+exportType.StoredProcedure+" :@" + string.Join(", :@",exportType.Parameters.GetType().GetProperties().Select(pinfo => pinfo.Name).ToArray());

             var session = Session.CreateSQLQuery(sql).SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<T>());

             foreach (var parameter in exportType.Parameters.GetType().GetProperties())
             {
                 session.SetParameter("@" + parameter.Name, parameter.GetValue(exportType.Parameters,null));
             }
            returnRequest.Obj = session.List<T>().ToList();

             return returnRequest;
         }
         catch (Exception exception )
         {
             returnRequest.Success = false;
             returnRequest.Message = exception.Message;
             returnRequest.Exception = exception;
             return returnRequest;

         }
     }
```

An example of a generic type - mapped to the output of the stored procedure & create an un-mapped object for the stored procedure parameters that gets attached to a patent object.

```
public class Integration_ExportRERW_Scores 
{
    public string SchoolId { get; set; }
    public string SSID { get; set; }
    public int LessonId { get; set; }
    public int ClassPeriod { get; set; }
    public string TeacherId { get; set; }
    public string LessonTitle { get; set; }
    public int RW4ComprehensionScore { get; set; }
    public int RW4WordPowerScore { get; set; }
    public int REComprehensionScore { get; set; }
    public int REVocabularyScore { get; set; }
    public int RE2ComprehensionScore { get; set; }
    public int RE2VocabularyScore { get; set; }
}

public class Integration_ExportRERW_Scores_Parameters
{
    public int DistrictId { get; set; }
}
```

Finally how it's implemented

```
 var export = service.ListSubscriptions().First().Export;
         var parameters = new Integration_ExportRERW_Scores_Parameters
         {
             DistrictId = 12060
         };
         export.Parameters = parameters;
         var fetch = service.ExportData<Integration_ExportRERW_Scores>(export);
```